# For-loop not working for count not increasing

Tags: javascript

Trying to get `i` to increase in the count because there are many RouteHops.

It starts with 1. It only counts to 1

```
let ln = resp.Rsult.details.length
let i = 0;
for (i = 1; i < ln; i++) {
  console.log(i)
  let resp2 =  (resp.Result.details).find(x => x.key == 'InternetGatewayDevice.TraceRouteDiagnostics.RouteHops.' + i + '.HopErrorCode').value 
  console.log('HOPERROR ===> ' + resp2)
  return resp2
```

Comment: `return resp2` returns from the current function without giving the `for` another chance to loop.

Comment: Unrelated, but it might be convenient to rework the code so it's easier to read, something like https://gist.github.com/davelnewton/ce4cf4c47ddd607302e1fd633b53479a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `return resp2` inside of the for loop. That will break the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You are exiting the for loop with the return command.

```
  return resp2
```

Comment: Also from the function, not just the loop.

Comment: Correct. Didn't point out that because his problem was why did the loop stop at 1. But you are absolutely right.